# Run LINQ query with date range check in C# with correct date format

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-3.5, jqwidget

I am getting trouble in running LINQ query and I strongly believe is because of date format. I am getting string values for dates and other tags in ASP.NET C# code-behind webMethod from $ajax jQuery function and I am converting string date to Convert.ToDateTime. Date been selected on web-page using jQWidget and format is coming as in following screen shot of alert

[image]

and following screen shot of code-behind debugging

[image]

### Ajax jQuery Function

```
  $("#ctl00_ContentArea_btnFilterStudent").click(function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            var givenDateFrom = $("#CldBoxStudentFilter_From").jqxDateTimeInput('getDate');

            var givenDateTo = $("#CldBoxStudentFilter_To").jqxDateTimeInput('getDate');

            if(givenDateFrom && givenDateTo)
            {

                var selectedFilteredValue = $("#<%=ddLStudentFilterList.ClientID%> option:selected").val();

               $.ajax({
                    url: 'TutorForm.aspx/FilterStudentListInRelationToStaffByDateRange',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ GivenStaffID: SelectStaffID, SelectFilterOption: selectedFilteredValue, FromDate: givenDateFrom, ToDate: givenDateTo }),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {

                        alert("success");
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.d);
                    }
                }).done(function (response) {

                });
```

### C# code

```
 [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static string FilterStudentListInRelationToStaffByDateRange(string GivenStaffID, string SelectFilterOption, string FromDate, string ToDate)
    {
        string returnList = string.Empty;

        bool StudentStaffRelationActive = false; 

        List<StudentInRelationToStaffModelView> studentStaffRelationObject = new List<StudentInRelationToStaffModelView>();

        //var queryList = StaffRelay.GetStudentsForRelationship(Convert.ToInt32(GivenStaffID), Convert.ToDateTime(FromDate), Convert.ToDateTime(ToDate), RelationshipStatus.None);


        if (SelectFilterOption.Equals("StudentFilterSelectAll"))
        {

            var queryList = StaffRelay.GetStudentsForRelationship(Convert.ToInt32(GivenStaffID), null, null, RelationshipStatus.None);

            var x = (from b in queryList
                    where b.RelationshipDateStart >= Convert.ToDateTime(FromDate) && b.RelationshipDateEnd <= Convert.ToDateTime(FromDate)
                    select b).ToList();

        //need help here......
```

Comment: Could you describe the problem in any words more than just "trouble"?

Comment: What is the "trouble"? Can you post the error you are getting?

Comment: From above code, I am getting 7 records in  var queryList so when I run link which is var x = linq code, I get 0 records I know for sure I should get 3 records to X but I am getting. Linq query without date range is working fine so I believe is something to do with date format here

Comment: @toxic - Have you debugged and checked in those 7 records are the dates falling in the range as per your condition? It should be straight forward.

Comment: yes it is ... but I am not getting result

Comment: Ok! let boil down to this, how to convert string ="2015-07-21T23:00:00.000Z" to {21/07/2015 00:00:00} in c#

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a time zone issue - client side +1 hour adjusted. You may have to specify the time zone of the date you are expecting on the server side.

```
    DateTime rawDate = Convert.ToDateTime(matchFromXmlSoccer.Date);
    TimeZoneInfo est = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time");
    DateTime targetDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(rawDate, est);
```